# Cannot import correctly maven properties with PropertiesFactoryBean and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in spring

Tags: spring, maven, datasource, placeholder, jrebel

I'm facing problems with a jdbc dynamic properties configurer. I try to explain what exactly the problem is.

When I do `mvn clean install` and right after I deploy the applications in my server (Weblogic 10.3.3), everything is correct, and all the applications work fine. But, every morning, when I try to redeploy the same applications, it was shown an error message like this:

```
Error creating bean with name 'path.to.my.bean.JDBCPropertiesFactoryBean#6015a10' defined in class path resource [spring/configuration/placeholder-jdbcproperties.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [
SELECT
  A.COLUMN1 || '.' || P.COLUMN2,
  COLUMN3
FROM
  T_TABLE_WITH_PROPERTIES${application.version} P,
  T_TABLE_WITH_PROPERTIES_2 G
WHERE G.ID = P.ID
]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

This `application.version` comes from maven pom.xml:

```
<properties>
  ...
  <application.version>MyVersion</application.version>
  ...
</properties>
```

The bean is:

```
<bean id="jdbcPlaceholderConfig"
class="path.to.my.bean.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> <!-- Class to extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -->
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
<property name="properties">
    <bean class="path.to.my.bean.JDBCPropertiesFactoryBean"> <!-- Class to extend PropertiesFactoryBean -->
        <property name="query">
            <value>
                SELECT
                    A.COLUMN1 || '.' || P.COLUMN2,
                    COLUMN3
                FROM
                    T_TABLE_WITH_PROPERTIES${application.version} P,
                    T_TABLE_WITH_PROPERTIES_2 G
                WHERE G.ID = P.ID
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ref.to.datasource.bean"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

So, every morning I have to rebuild with maven, and the loop starts again.

Additional information: I try to use JRebel too, but I'm not sure where can be the problem, maybe this is relevant.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

This how I generate the `rebel.xml`:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
      <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
        <rootPath>PATH\TO\MY\SIS_VOB</rootPath>
        <addResourcesDirToRebelXml>true</addResourcesDirToRebelXml>
        <alwaysGenerate>true</alwaysGenerate>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I've just realized that with `<executions>...<goal>generate</goal>...</executions>`, when I do `mvn clean install`, without `jrebel:generate`, the `rebel.xml` files are always generated, so maybe I have to delete the executions tag, and generate the `rebel.xml` files once with `jrebel:generate`, and then, edit the `rebel.xml` and do again `mvn clean install`.

Would be that correct?

Thanks.

UPDATE WITH THE SOLUTION:

This is the final version of maven jrebel plugin in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
      <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
        <rootPath>PATH\TO\MY\SIS_VOB</rootPath>
        <addResourcesDirToRebelXml>true</addResourcesDirToRebelXml>
        <alwaysGenerate>true</alwaysGenerate>
      </configuration>
      <!-- executions tag out! to not regenerate files always -->
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

To create the rebel.xml:

```
mvn jrebel:generate
```

Then, if we want, we can modify the `rebel.xml` files if we want to exclude some files, like `*.properties`, as Henri's answer.

And that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you're using resource filtering with JRebel, as the application looks up the bean's xml in its unfiltered form from the project working directory (as per `rebel.xml`).

To resolve this, you'll need to update `rebel.xml` for that module, adding exclude for that particular XML file - see [here](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html#exclude).

[Example](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-doesnt-work-with-maven-war-filtering-and-intellij/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try it. But I have another question, this `rebel.xml` is generate automatically, Do I have to update the file manually? or Is there any way to do it automatically?.

Comment: How are you generating `rebel.xml`? Via Maven plugin or from IDE? If customizing the `rebel.xml` manually, remove the JRebel Maven plugin and drop the customized file to the `src/main/resources`. If via IDE, just make sure you're using newest IDE plugins and when prompted, don't allow the `rebel.xml` to be regenerated. For further questions contact *support@zeroturnaround.com*.

Comment: @henri-vik I've just update the post with more information.

Comment: Thank you Henri Vilk, finally this was the solution. I've just update the question with the correct way to do that.