# Could not resolve placeholder with Spring in a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, weblogic, placeholder

I have headache with this problem, which I thought I had resolved but I didn't.

I'm working with a multi-module maven project, Spring and Weblogic, among other technologies. There are some beans with placeholders, which can be fetch from database or pom.xml.

Right now I've have a problem with a particular bean that looks like this:

```
...
<bean id="idOfMyBean" abstract="true"
    class="path.to.my.class"
    p:dataSource-ref="path.to.my.datasource"
    p:schemaName="${placeholder.that.comes.from.database}"
    p:applicationVersion="${application.version}">
</bean>
...
```

This bean is inside a project which is a jar project, and this jar goes inside my ear project.

My parent pom.xml looks like this:

```
...
<properties>
  ...
  <!-- Dependencies versions. -->
  <spring.version>2.5.6.SEC01</spring.version>
  <spring.ws.version>1.5.9</spring.ws.version>
  <spring.integration.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
  <hibernate.version>3.5.3-Final</hibernate.version>
  <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <application.version>MYVERSION</application.version>
  ...
</properties>
...
```

As far I understand, when I do `mvn clean install`, the placeholder in the bean is replaced with `MYVERSION`. In fact, if I look inside my ear project, I usually use `7zip` to do that, I open the jar and look for the xml file which contains the ben, I can see that is correctly replaced:

```
...
<bean id="idOfMyBean" abstract="true"
    class="path.to.my.class"
    p:dataSource-ref="path.to.my.datasource"
    p:schemaName="${placeholder.that.comes.from.database}"
    p:applicationVersion="MYVERSION">
</bean>
...
```

Well, when I try to start my applications, it is thrown the following error:

```
Starting application my-application.
<15-jul-2015 08H52' CEST> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating start operation for application, my-application [archive: null], to MY_CLUSTER .>
..................Failed to start the application with status failed
Current Status of your Deployment:
Deployment command type: start
Deployment State       : failed
Deployment Message     : weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:Invalid bean definition with name 'idOfMyBean' defined in class path resource [path/to/my/bean.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.version'
No stack trace available.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\sisii\script\menu_setup.py", line 200, in ?
  File "C:\sisii\script\.\lib\menu_system.py", line 110, in run
  File "C:\sisii\script\menu_setup.py", line 195, in <lambda>
  File "C:\sisii\script\.\lib\config.py", line 2233, in startAll
  File "C:\Users\a554236\AppData\Local\Temp\wlst_module12913752580026045681.py", line 320, in startApplication
    at weblogic.management.scripting.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:48)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.WLSTUtils.throwWLSTException(WLSTUtils.java:188)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.JSR88DeployHandler.startApplication(JSR88DeployHandler.java:768)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.WLScriptContext.startApplication(WLScriptContext.java:844)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

weblogic.management.scripting.ScriptException: weblogic.management.scripting.ScriptException: Error occured while performing startApplication : Failed to start the application with status failed

<15-jul-2015 08H53' CEST> <Warning> <JNDI> <BEA-050001> <WLContext.close() was called in a different thread than the one in which it was created.>
```

How is that possible?

The problem could be related with another question I asked before, [Cannot import correctly maven properties with PropertiesFactoryBean and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914884/cannot-import-correctly-maven-properties-with-propertiesfactorybean-and-property), but I though I had resolved, indeed in that question there was another bean which I had problem, but that placeholder problem was with those from database, and now is with those from pom.

Tell me if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings.